# GitHub forked project: right way to have own gh-pages

Tags: github, git-fork, github-pages

When a github project is forked the gh-pages related to initial project. Can i have a modifications in gh-pages and do not synchronize it with parent project? the same question is for trivial README in master-branch of fork.

Comment: So you want to push code back, but not the pages?

Comment: Yes, push back only some files and not all. in context of a  pull request on github

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could keep your modifications separate per branches:

- one branch for modification you might want to push back with a pull request
- one branch for private modifications (ad you would merge the first branch on the second regularly, to keep *all* combined evolutions in one - private - branch)

Comment: so i have only do `git checkout -b gh-pages` ? and this new branch will not be included in pull request?

Comment: @Yurij73 yes, pull request (https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests) is limited to the branch you select when you make said request. If you don't select your `gh-pages` branch, it won't be part of the pull request.